# Add Geometry attributes error

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I have a point shapefile on which I would like to use the "Add geometry attributes: tool in order to add x and y coordinates using a GCS that I am interested it. When I run this tool I get the runtime error:

> "The field is not nullable (Point_M)".

I don't understand why I am getting this error. AddGeometryAttributes is supposed to add this field on its own, I have no role in the field Point_M. In fact it doesn't even exist before I run the tool. This is one of the outputs of AddGeometryAttributes.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: Your feature class has M values, you need to set the M of your point (to 0 perhaps) before you can store it. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000006t000000 Can you share your code (edit your question) for creation and perhaps I can suggest something. If your feature class is empty then create a new one that doesn't have M see environment Output Has M Values http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000007000000

Answer (score 2):

@Michael is probably be right. Your point feature class has [M-values](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/feature-class-basics.htm) enabled, but you haven't set the M-value for each point. In fact, if you're not using the feature class for routing or reckoning distances (like mileposts), you don't need M-values enabled.

An alternative to using the "Add Geometry" tool is to make two new fields called "X" and "Y" and Field Calculate them using the Python syntax: `!SHAPE.firstPoint.X!` and `!SHAPE.firstPoint.Y!`, assuming there are no multi-part features.

[image: Calculate Coordinate XY Example]